Plumber ignores custom error for fromJSON
I am working on building custom error handling using plumber. I have one custom error function that is working. missing_val_check checks the dataframe for missing columns and if anything is missing, it returns a 400 status code and a custom message. This works the same whether I send the data via Swagger or curl
I wish to do something similar with invalid JSON, safely_parse_json returning a 400 status and a custom message, but it seems my function is not operating as expected. If I use Swagger and pass the data, I see a 500 status and default error. If I use curl to pass the data, I see the custom error.
the code and returns a simpleError (rather than "api_error") with 500 status.
Here is my plumber.R
library(plumber)
library(tidyverse)

api_error <- function(message, status, res) {
  res$status = status
  error <- structure(
    list(message = message, 
         status = status),
    class = c("api_error", "error", "condition")
  )
  signalCondition(error)
}

missing_val_check <- function(x, res) {
  
  cols_with_na <- names(x)[apply(is.na(x), 2, any)]
  if(length(cols_with_na) > 0 ){
    msg = paste("NA values found in columns:", paste(cols_with_na, collapse = ", "))
    api_error(message = msg, status = 400, res=res)
  }
  
}

safely_parse_json <- function(req, res){
  parse <- purrr::safely(.f = jsonlite::fromJSON, otherwise = NULL)
  result <- parse(req$postBody, simplifyVector = FALSE)
  if(length(result[["error"]]) > 0){
    
    api_error(message = paste("JSON Error:", result[["error"]][["message"]]), 
              status = 400, res = res)
    
  } else {
    return(result[["result"]])
  }
}

#* @param req:object
#* @serializer json
#* @post /test
function(req, res) {
  parsed <- dplyr::bind_rows(
    safely_parse_json(req, res)
    )
  
  df <- parsed |>
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), \(x) ifelse(x ==0, NA, x))) # force a NA for demo purposes
  missing_val_check(df, res)
  paste(parsed)
}

Call plumber as usual:
pr("plumber.R") %>%
  pr_run(port=8000)

I am using Swagger to test and see the status codes - they don't show up in the terminal for some reason.
Example 1 - works as expected, no errors intended
{"a":4, "b":3} or curl --data '{"a":4, "b":3}' http://localhost:8000/test
Example 2 - works as expected, 1 error intended - 400 status and custom error in terminal and Swagger
{"a":4, "b":0} or curl --data '{"a":4, "b":0}' http://localhost:8000/test
Example 3 - does not work as expected, 1 error intended - 500 status and default message in Swagger, custom message in terminal
{"a":4, "b:0} or curl --data '{"a":4, "b:0}' http://localhost:8000/test

I cannot reproduce. When I use curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" --data '{"a":4, "b:0}' http://localhost:9999/test from the shell, it outputs 400 as you expect. (And when done without the -s/-o/-w args, I get the custom error message.)

That code indeed returns a 400 and the custom error message expected. It doesn't align with Swagger though, which is sending this code curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"req\": {\"a\":4, \"b:0}}".
